# Self Html Code with Selenium Htmlunit

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

How do I get the html code for WebElement using HtmlUnitDriver on Java?

```
System.out.println((String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element));
```

This returns all the html code inside that element, not the element itself.
Also if the node is self closing tag like `input` or `img`, it returns empty string.
Lastly, `element.getAttribute("innerHTML")` doesn't work with `HtmlUnitDriver`.